# Using a looper on a separate thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

**Background:**

I'm trying to show the movement of a bus by incrementally moving a marker via `handler.postDelayed` until it reaches from one stop to the next stop.

I want it to repeat for the next stop after a certain amount of time, so I tried using a looper on a separate thread as it was too much work for the main UI thread.

**Problem:**

Because I am updating the position of a marker, I need to set a new position to it after every second, however when running the code I run across errors stating that it is not on the main UI thread (see the bottom of this post).

The error points to the variable storing the busMarker, which I assume can only be modified by the thread it was created on.

I've tried `runOnUiThread()` but i'll still get other errors, such as null values which shouldn't be because I assigned values to them, but only in the main thread.

I'm assuming there is a much cleaner way than having to continuously return to the main thread, so how do I achieve this?

**Creating the thread**

```
private class ThreadClass extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Looper.prepare();

        moveBusMarker();

        if (passedStops.size() != stops.size()) {

            Looper.loop();
        }
        else {

            Looper.myLooper().quit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Running the thread**

```
    if (passedStops.size() != 0 && passedStops.size() != stops.size()) {
        thread.start();
    }
```

**Executing the Movement**

```
// set up a timer
final long limit = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds) - 1000;
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

final Stop NextStop = nextStop;

final Handler handler1 = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.d("", "The bus is currently at " + busPosition.toString());

        // get the current bus' position
        double lat = busPosition.latitude;
        double lon = busPosition.longitude;

        // add the difference to the bus position to move it closer
        lat = lat + latDifference;
        lon = lon + lonDifference;
        busPosition = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        Log.d("", "The bus has moved to " + busPosition.toString());

        // set the new position to the marker representing the bus movement
        busMarker.setPosition(busPosition);


        // it hasn't reached the next stop, continue to animate
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < limit) {
            handler1.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

        // else the time is up i.e. the bus has reached the next stop, so set the new target
        else {
            Log.d("", "The bus has passed " + NextStop.getName());

            passedStops.add(NextStop);
            Log.d("", passedStops.toString());

            createPolyline();
        }
    }

};

handler1.post(runnable);
```

**The error logged**

```
Process: com.example.sanj.fyp, PID: 18904
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
        at com.google.l.a.cd.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ca.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aj.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.t.onTransact(SourceFile:73)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.l$a$a.setPosition(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.setPosition(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.sanj.fyp.main.fragment.LiveServiceFragment$2$1.run(LiveServiceFragment.java:423)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at com.example.sanj.fyp.main.fragment.LiveServiceFragment$ThreadClass.run(LiveServiceFragment.java:115)
```

Comment: first of all: why do you need a separate thread just to make so simpke operation as moving the bus?

Comment: @pskink the screen goes black and the log outputs that there's too much work on the main thread. For usability purposes, I do not want this, especially as I want the app to always show the marker moving.

Comment: i never saw any android animation that needs to be run in the background thread,  You must be doing something very wrong

Comment: @pskink I am not exactly animating. I'm moving the marker bit by bit across a polyline. Currently it stops at the next stop, but I want it to continue to the next stop, which is where I get the problem I just explained in the previous comment.

Comment: see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#video_animating_markers

Comment: @pskink thank you for link but that goes from A to b seamlessly. I want to portray the actual movement of public transport for it to reach the designated stop, when the departure time is the real time, as to why I stop the movement of the marker after a certain amount of time

Comment: and in order to do that you don't need any background thread...

Comment: So how can I do it without the screen going black, using the main thread?

Comment: how can i know why your screen goes bkack not seeing the code?

Comment: @pskink well I only put the above code there because, without the new thread and looper initialisation, everything was working fine. Running the new thread is called in the OnCreateView method too, so if it's taking long in there then, from past experience, it would turn black because nothing is returned right?

Comment: i don't really know what you mean, sorry...

Comment: @pskink so I decided to try and do it again without having to make a separate thread, and it worked this time for some weird reason. Thanks

Comment: @pskink if you can add an answer i'd be happy to accept it as the right one

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to figure what thread your handler1 variable is created from. Make sure that it's on the UI thread. Or quickfix:

```
handler1 = new Handler(context.getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method moveBusMarker() is run in the background thread that's why you get this error.
Try the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class. Use the doInBackground method to run your looper and then update the UI in the postExecute method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

is ought to fix your problem.